# Java SimpleDateFormat does not parse correctly (I am using the correct uppercase/lowercase letters..)

Tags: java, parsing, time, simpledateformat

I know this has been asked several times and I am risking a downvote/duplicate close, but most of the questions posted here were resolved by chaing YYYY into yyyy..so, searching does not really help :/

These are the given timestamps inside the block

```
date new Block: 2017-11-02T06:17:05.079481
date old Block: 2017-11-02T06:17:04.608960
```

My conversion code:

```
 public static Date getDate(JSONObject block){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    try {
       return sdf.parse(block.get("timestamp").toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

And this is the result of parse

```
date new block: Thu Nov 02 06:18:24 KST 2017 
date old block: Thu Nov 02 06:27:12 KST 2017
```

How is that possible? The new block was created after the old block, as seen in the timestamp. but now it is the other way around

Comment: day of month is represented by lowercase `d`

Comment: Instead of `DD` use dd

Comment: Searching for "[How to use SimpleDateFormat Java"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) would have helped.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: `SSS` is milliseconds. You're trying to parse microseconds. Are you able to use java.time.* instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is that possible? The new block was created before the old block, as seen in the timestamp. but now it is the other way around

`S` in a `SimpleDateFormat` format string always represents milliseconds - not just "fractions of a second" which is what you're assuming at the moment.

Your "new" block is being parsed as adding 79481 milliseconds whereas the "old" block has 608960.

That explains the results, but doesn't give you a way forward. There are two options here:

- Use `java.time.*` - this is a much more modern API, with nanosecond precision instead of millisecond precision.
- Drop the last three characters of your inputs, and parse to only millisecond precision.

Comment: @InDaPond: It's a much cleaner API than java.util.Date/Calendar... I'd thoroughly recommend moving to that in general as far as you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Jon Skeet’s knowledgable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47454122/5772882), using `java.time` isn’t hard. The date-time format from your JSON block is ISO 8601, the standard format for exchange of date and time data, and the `java.time` classes parse this format as their default, that is, without the need for an explicit format:

```
    String blockTimestamp = "2017-11-02T06:17:05.079481";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(blockTimestamp);
```

If you try printing the resulting dateTime, you will again see its default format, ISO 8601, since this is also what its `toString` method produces: `2017-11-02T06:17:05.079481`.

The potential downside of `LocalDateTime` is it doesn’t represent an unambiguous point on the timeline. So if you know in which time zone to interpret the date and time, you will probably want to convert it to a `ZonedDateTime`, for example:

```
    ZoneId koreaTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul");
    ZonedDateTime koreaDateTime = dateTime.atZone(koreaTimeZone);
```

This yields `2017-11-02T06:17:05.079481+09:00[Asia/Seoul]`.

Answer (score -1):

In your Simple Date Format, you need to change **'DD'** to lowercase **'dd'**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

This will hopefully solve your problem.

**EDIT: Same is the case with hours. **
Replace **'HH'** with **'hh'** (lowercase).

Thanks

Comment: This resolves the wrong month problem, but the timestamp is still incorrect now

Comment: InDaPond, edited the upper comment.

Please check and validate.

Comment: Out of the JavaDoc:H for Hour in day(0-23) and h for hour in am/pm. So capital H should be correct?

Comment: No, the OP definitely *doesn't* want to go to `hh`. There's no am/pm specifier.

Comment: The format is ISO 8601. This uses a 24 hour clock, so capital `HH` is correct.